# Arc Length in two dimensions by integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, linear-approximation

I'm really at the end of my wits on this problem. Basically I'm trying to find arc length. The vector-valued function is: $R=\langle t,\sqrt{t}\rangle$
 and $t\ge0$.

We're looking for the length of the arc between $0\leq t\leq3$. I know that you basically have to integrate the magnitude of the tangent vector over the interval specified, and to this end

I got as far as the $\int_0^3 \sqrt(1+1/4t)dt.$ On that note, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to integrate this. I've tried factoring, simplifying, substitution (which seemed to make it worse), and anything else I could think of. Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there an easier method? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the indefinite integral looks quite complicated, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eqeni0om0fm)...

Comment: The language is called MathJax, and a quick tutorial can be found here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Start with a change of variable such that $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{4 t}+1}=u$$ which means $$t=\frac{1}{4 \left(u^2-1\right)}$$ $$dt=-\frac{u}{2 \left(u^2-1\right)^2}du$$ Then $$\int \sqrt{\frac{1}{4 t}+1}~dt=-\int \frac{u^2}{2 \left(u^2-1\right)^2}~du$$ Now use partial fraction decomposition. The result is quite simple.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: awesome... I didn't think of using partial fraction decomposition. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. In reality, all comes from the change of variable. After, it is simple. Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm stuck again. I believe I have the correct partial fraction decomposition and was about to attempt to integrate it, but i can't figure out how to change the limits of integration. I keep getting a 0 in the denominator. I'm trying to find what u is when t=0 and when t=3, or should I use a different approach?

Comment: Just replace from the definition of $u$ : the lower bound is $\infty$ and the upper bound is $\sqrt {13/12}$.

Comment: I'm still completely lost on this part. I need t to go from 0 to 3. I've tried using 1+1/t=u^2 to solve for u when t is 0 and when it's 3, but that's not working. Or am I supposed to put the result of the indefinite integral of u into a definite integral of t?

Comment: Go back to $u=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4 t}+1}$ and look at the value of $u$ when $t$ goes to $0$ (answer : $\infty$) and  when $t$ goes to $3$ (answer : $\sqrt {13/12}$)

Comment: so far i have $ -\frac12 (\int \frac{1}{u^2-1}du -\int \frac{1}{(u^2-1)^2}du$ which I integrated and got $-\frac12 (\ln(u^2-1)+\frac{1}{u^2-1})+C$ Does that seem right so far?

Comment: ohhhhh. dur. thanks!!

Comment: Your antiderivative is not correct.

Comment: It wasn't the lack of parentheses around the u^2-1 was it?